# Display a result of debugger's step as an inline text

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

For my debugger extension I'd like to implement a functionality from the following image where a step can ask a debugger client to show an inlined text with the result of the step.

I've read the DAP documentation thoroughly but still don't have a clue how this can be implemented or if it's even possible to implement. What request or event do I have to implement?

By the way, how is this function of debbuger client called?

[image: Result of step as an inline text]

Comment: Just a guess: maybe that's editor decorations from the variables view? The debug adapter can use the variables list it provides anyway, to generate such decorations and remove them once the debug session is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With vscode v1.54, see [Inline value provider](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_54.md#inline-value-provider-api)

> Today the Show Inline Values feature of VS Code's debugger is based on
> a generic implementation in VS Code core, and doesn't provide
> customizability through settings or extensibility via extensions. As a
> consequence, it is not a perfect fit for all languages and sometimes
> shows incorrect values because it doesn't understand the underlying
> source language. For this reason, we are working on an extension API
> that allows to replace the built-in implementation completely or to
> replace parts of the implementation with custom code.
>
> In this milestone we've made a first implementation of the [proposed
> API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/57c918802b88902adc2094d70c8fd3aa29a13102/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts#L667-L813) available.

And much more at the first link including sample code.  So vscode is adding a true API for inline values rather than depending on `Decorations` anymore.